# Maui Keystore generation keeps falling into Infinite loop

Tags: c#, android, maui

I am using maui to publish an app to android play store.
I am trying to create an keystore file.

keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -alias key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
I am using this line of code in the PowerShell
and after i type all the info, After i type yes in the confirmation part, it just goes back to the name input part. Am i doing something Wrong?

I tried typing Yes YES yes and it didnt work. I just press enter and it also went straight to name input part.

Comment: Have you followed the official document [Publish a .NET MAUI app for Android with the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-7.0) ?